# Set of Discontinuities for a Function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to answer a question regarding the set of discontinuities for a function, but I want to make sure that I understand the setup correctly. Here it is:

---

Let {$x_n$} be a sequence of real numbers defined by:
$$
x_n =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2k},  & \text{if $n=2k-1$} \\[2ex]
\frac{1}{2k-1}, & \text{if $n=2k$}
\end{cases}
k\ge1 \text{ and } n\ge1
$$

Set $\epsilon_n$ $=$ $(\frac{1}{2})^n$ and define $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ by

$$
f(x)= \sum_{n: \text{ }x_n \le x}\epsilon_n
$$

1. Compute $f(0), \text{ }f(-1), \text{ }f(1), \text{ }f(\sqrt2),\text{ }f(\frac{1}{2})$
2. Determine the set of discontinuities for the function and justify your claim.

---

To answer #1 I began by creating a table for the first six values of the sequence:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & \text{1} & \text{2} & \text{3} & \text{4} & \text{5} & \text{6}\\
\hline
x_n & \frac{1}{2} & 1 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{5}\\
\epsilon_n &\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{16} & \frac{1}{32} & \frac{1}{64} \\
\end{array}
$$

If I am approaching this correctly, $f(0)=0$ since there are no $x_n \le 0$ (although the sequence appears to converge to $0$). Likewise: $f(-1)=0$. However, things become unclear with $x=\sqrt2$ since all of the $x_n$ appear to be less than $\sqrt2$. Is there something amiss in this approach?

Comment: Your approach is fine. As you correctly state, all $x_n$ are $\le \sqrt{2}$, so the sum in the definition of $f(x)$ will be taken over all $n\ge 1$. Can you calculate that sum?

Comment: @Ingix: Let me know if you agree: f(0)=0, f(-1)=0, f(1)=1, f(sqrt(2))=1. However, I am unclear about the case where x= 1/2; here we exclude the value 1/4 from the summation since 1>1/2, however that series still presumably converges to 1.